# TestFlight & Release Run Crash?

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash, release, testflight

I know this has been asked and answered, but none of the issues seems to be related to mine? Either way, someone help me :\

---

> When I run the app downloaded from TestFlight OR run the app through
>   Xcode as Release (not debug) I get this error from my device log (not
>   Xcode's log)

[image]

> This is what Xcode shows me

```
AppName`std::__1::vector<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >::allocate:
->  0x103206110 <+0>:  .long  0x00000000                ; unknown opcode
    0x103206114 <+4>:  .long  0x00000000                ; unknown opcode
    0x103206118 <+8>:  .long  0x00000000                ; unknown opcode
    0x10320611c <+12>: .long  0x00000000                ; unknown opcode
```

**FYI:** I am more than certain it's a package error / pre-interface issue - meaning, I removed everything from the build (all classes) and had it load a blank **VC** to start, and I get the exact same error.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem since?

Comment: Had to make an entirely new project - copy it all over. Seemed to fix the issue. 
Must have been a problem with a pod installed. who knows

Answer (score 1):

I had to struggle with this for two days. I had the same device log and also same xcode log. I tried all sorts of fixes and regenerated certificates. In my case, it was due to pod file that was outdated, it was google maps restricted to version 3.0.0, updating the pod solved the issue.

Check if you have something like this in your pod file.

pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.0.0'

pod 'GooglePlaces', '3.0.0'

Specifying the version will not update it, so even after you tried updating the pods some pods may not have updated. Please check this first before going all out on build settings, link binary status, creating new certificates, using legacy build system or any other over the top fixes.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I ended up make a completely new project with everything I need copied over